# Using WHERE SQL Command in Excel using VB.Net

Tags: sql, excel, vb.net

I am having difficulty in constructing SQL Commands in VB.Net wherein my project is connected to Excel via OLEDB.

```
Select * From [Sheet$]
```

This SQL Command works but whenever I try to add another SQL Command `WHERE` so that I could filter the data and I only wanted to be shown.
I have headers in my excel file, the `Name` header is the 4th column equivalent to Column letter: `D`.

```
Select * From [Sheet$] Where Name='Xander'
```

it doesn't work, it shows nothing. What is the correct `'WHERE`' SQL Command for Excel to OLEDB Connection?

By the way this is the code I am working on

```
 Dim conn As OleDbConnection
 Dim adapt As OleDbDataAdapter
 Dim dts As DataSet
 Dim excel As String = My.Settings.DefaultDirectory

 conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excel + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
 conn.Open()

 adapt = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [Sheet$] where NAME='Xander'", conn)
 dts = New DataSet

 adapt.Fill(dts, "[Sheet$]")
 DataGridView1.DataSource = dts
 DataGridView1.DataMember = "[Sheet$]"

 conn.Close()
```

Comment: What is your connectionstring and do you have headers columns?

Comment: Is `CellHeader` the header/column?

Comment: Edited the post. @Codexer yes that it is the header/column

Comment: Try `Select * from [Sheet$] Where [NAME]='Xander'`

Comment: @Codexer, holy groot friend! Thank you, I havent thought of adding brackets in the Header Name thank you. Kindly write the answer down so I could mark it as Solved/Answered. Thank you again.

Comment: You need to add HDR=YES to your connectionstring if you have headers in your sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enclose brackets around your column names to escape them. Also `Name` is a reserved word, so you must escape it.

```
 Select * from [Sheet$] Where [NAME]='Xander'
```

Comment: follow up question, how about [DATE]='4/2/2017'

I think it is working with letter characters but not with Date format.

Comment: Did I do it right? Select * from [Q2$] Where [DATE]='#3/2/2018'

Comment: `Select * from [Q2$] Where [DATE]=#3/2/2018#` this is how you do it... you need to remove ticks and wrap date in `#`...

Comment: Man you're a lifesaver, I'm kinda new in Excel SQL coz I only get used to Database SQLs, but man Thank you. I think this is all for now..